# I want to limit number of decimals after point

Tags: javascript

```
${record.exchangerate?string?replace('[^.,0-9]','','r')
```

I have this exchange rate and I want to limitate the number of decimals to be only 4
At this moment per example is showing: : `0.85813707`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toLocaleString`

Example:

```
var myNum = 0.591334;
console.log(myNum.toLocaleString("en", {maximumFractionDigits: 4})); // 0.5913
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use toFixed() method and convert the returned value to a number like that:

```js
const number = 0.85813707

// first method using + operator
const fixedNumber1 = +number.toFixed(4)

// second method using Number function
const fixedNumber2 = Number(number.toFixed(4))

// third method using parseFloat function
const fixedNumber3 = parseFloat(number.toFixed(4))

console.log(fixedNumber1, fixedNumber2, fixedNumber3)
// expected output: 0.8581 0.8581 0.8581

console.log(typeof fixedNumber1, typeof fixedNumber2, typeof fixedNumber3)
// expected output: number number number
```

Answer (score 0):

The method toFixed might be of help here. Lets take your example

```
let num = 0.85813707
num.toFixed(4)
```

will output "0.8581"

Note, this converts it to string, and you'll need to convert it back to a number if you want to use it as one.

More documentation about this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use toFixed() to do that

```
var excFloatValue = parseFloat(exchangerate).toFixed(4)
```